# String portion after variable in .write() being put on new line in Python

Tags: python, newline

I am relatively new to Python. So please excuse my naivety. While trying to write a string to a file, the portion of the string after the variable is put on a new line and it should not be. I am using python 2.6.5 btw

```
arch = subprocess.Popen("info " + agent + " | grep '\[arch\]' | awk '{print $3}'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
arch, err = arch.communicate()
strarch = str(arch)
with open ("agentInfo", "a") as info:
        info.write("Arch Bits: " + strarch + " bit")
        info.close()
os.system("cat agentInfo")
```

Desireded output:

```
"Arch Bits: 64 bit"
```

Actual output:

```
"Arch Bits: 64
bits"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `str(arch)` has a trailing new line, you can remove that using `str.strip` or `str.rstrip`:

```
strarch = str(arch).strip()   #removes all types of white-space characters
```

or:

```
strarch = str(arch).rstrip('\n') #removes only trailing '\n'
```

And you can also use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) here:

```
strarch = str(arch).rstrip('\n')
info.write("{}: {} {}".format("Arch Bits", strarch, "bits"))
```

---

Note that there's no need of `info.close()`, [`with` statement automatically closes the file for you.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#predefined-clean-up-actions)